# POST multiple values

Tags: php

I have a loop which generates a couple of fields which could be field in. I want to POST all the values from these fields into another php page.
The first page:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
print "

    <form action='2.php' method='post' id='test_form'>
        <input name='value-$i' type='text' />
        <input id='send' name='send' type='submit' value='Sent'  />
    </form>

";
}
```

The second page:

```
while ( ) {
$valuer= $_POST['value'];
}
```

Comment: Why not just iterate through `$_POST`?

Comment: In addition to the answers blow, I'd recommend moving the `<form>` and `input:submit` tag OUTSIDE the `for` loop.

Comment: Great recommendation. Iterate through $_POST is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name='value[$i]' type='text' />
                  ^--^---- note the []
```

Then

```
$fifth_value = $_POST['value'][5];
```

Comment: In that way I would get only the fifth value. What I would like is to have (in this case) 10 POST values in the second php. For example:
Value1
Value2
Value3
....
Foreaach or while loop would be helpful but I don't know how to form it.

Comment: `$_POST['value']` will be an array that contains ALL Of those values. I'm just demonstrating how you'd access ONE of those values. e.g. try doing `var_dump($_POST['value'])`